# EF6 How to create missing mdf

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using EF6 with migrations enabled.  I have a project that I decided to nuke and then re-pull from SVN.  I didn't realize/know that the connected database (a localdb .mdf file stored in APP_DATA) was not checked in, and I'm not sure I want it to be anyway.

EF is not creating the datafile on startup, I tried changing the initializer to CreateDatabaseIfNotExists, but it's not working.  I don't see any command line option to create it, and running "update-database" fails because the datafile doesn't exist.  How do I create it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's still relevant to you but
you can always remove your migrations folder and add a DropCreateDatabaseAlways seeder:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext() : base("SomeDBName")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyDbContext>());
        }
    }
```